# Error: an expression of non-boolean type specified

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from database where CREATION DATE >= "2018-11-10 00:00:00.0"
```

I'm new to the SQL, Anything wrong in this statement ??

I'm getting this error, an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Comment: single-quotes for strings.

Comment: thanks for the response, Still same error @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: Can't have a space in a column name. (Unless perhaps it's back-quoted, but even then I think it's disallowed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming "CREATION DATE" is your actual field. You need to put brackets around it, so it sees it as a a field.

```
SELECT * 
FROM database 
WHERE [CREATION DATE] >= "2018-11-10 00:00:00.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would recommend using backticks to escape the column name and single quotes for the date.  You don't need the time component either.

So:

```
select *
from database
where `CREATION DATE` >= '2018-11-10'
```

The standard escape character is double quotes, so you can use them for the identifier as well:

```
select *
from database
where "CREATION DATE" >= '2018-11-10'
```

But the best approach is to remove the space so escaping is not necessary:

```
alter table database rename column `CREATION DATE` to creation_date;
```

Then you can simply use:

```
select *
from database
where creation_date >= '2018-11-10'
```